# Use wsdl to create server for integration testing

Tags: java, maven, server, wsdl, code-generation

I have a WSDL file from a server that implements some webservices. I have created client-code with Axis2, but want to build some integration tests that deal with server-timouts.

To do that, I want to create a server-stub and have the methods just `sleep` longer than the configured client-timeout.

Is there an easy way to generate an scaffold-like server running the services from the WSDL?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Axis2, you can use [WSDL2Java](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/reference.html) to generate the server skeleton code to which you can then add your own testing code. By default WSDL2Java generates client code, but it can be used both ways with the server arguments.

Another approach would be to create a [SoapUI mock service](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-mocking/service-mocking-overview/) to which you could add Groovy [scripts](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-mocking/creating-dynamic-mockservices/) to make it more dynamic.